# Is there a way to specify default ordering for haystack?

Tags: django, sorting, django-haystack

Can I specify a default ordering for haystack search as we could do with Meta.ordering in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default ordering is the relevance score to keywords (by backends), and, after checking haystack 2.0 code I'm sure that we could not alter the default ordering w/o using [`.order_by()`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#order-by) method explicitly. You could provide a shortcut method to return a `SearchQuerySet` w/ `order_by` specified to work around this.